# Error : Action "Iframe" not found in the module "API"

Tags: matomo

When exporting in an iframe a particular page using the Widgetize feature, when I try to export a report's data, and click on "Export this dataset in other formats" it opens a new window with the error : Error : Action "Iframe" not found in the module "API". The issue is coming up for the list tab in the iframe. It is working fine for the Charts tab.
What I do not understand is the same action iframe works for the module widgetize for the Charts tab and the same action iframe isnt found in the module widgetize for the List tab.

Can you please let us know how we can rectify this issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on https://demo.matomo.cloud ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.